# Schema.org SearchAction error for Google Sitelinks Search Box: "valueName: missing and required"

Tags: google-search, schema.org, microdata

We are using the Schema.org `SearchAction` on our site in hopes to get the Sitelinks Search Box showing on the Google Search results. I have implemented the code exactly as it says on [Google's Developer Page](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) but it is still returning errors when I test it in [Google's Test Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).

Here is the code I am using:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.examplesite.com"/>
    <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
        <meta itemprop="target" content="http://www.examplesite.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={q}"/>
        <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> [image: Structured Data Testing Tool Error]

I would like to use Microdata if I can because so far all of our markup uses that. Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: It was [a bug](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/8jN5M7UHkEU/wNZr_VvN1TcJ) in Google’s Testing Tool. The markup from the question (and Googles own documentation) now works again. So there’s no need for the following alternative.

---

It’s not clear if this is just a temporary bug with their [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), or if their documentation for the [Sitelinks Search Box](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) is no longer accurate.

If you think their rules changed (and they forget updating the documentation), you could fix it by providing a [`PropertyValueSpecification`](http://schema.org/PropertyValueSpecification) item and its [`valueName`](http://schema.org/valueName) property (as the error message suggests):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
    <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com"/> <!-- changed from 'meta' to 'link', as it’s required by HTML5 and Microdata -->
    <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
        <meta itemprop="target" content="http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={q}"/>
        <div itemprop="query-input" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValueSpecification">
          <meta itemprop="valueName" content="q"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FWIW, this gives an "all good" for the "Sitelinks Search Box" in the Structured Data Testing Tool.

Comment: Does the {q} in target and the q in valueName need to match the actual search value the user entered? That was something I didn't totally understand from the documentation. So I just static set it to match the letter our search result page uses for the searches.

Comment: The string inside the curly braces `{` and `}` is just a placeholder, it doesn’t matter which one you choose (it just has to match the value of `valueName`). In your example, the query parameter for the search is the same as the placeholder, but it doesn’t have to be. You could use, for example, this `target` URI: `http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={foobar}`, and then you’d have to use this `valueName` value: `foobar`. And yes, it’s static (it just tells search engines which string they have to replace to generate a valid search URL for your site).

Comment: @Nick: I updated my answer: your original markup now works again.

Comment: Will it hurt anything if I do it the way you have it? We already have the code live so I figure I could just leave it unless it might cause issues.

Comment: @njm5785: I guess only people from Google could answer this. If it works in their Testing Tool (and then also in Google Search), you are probably fine, at least for now.